# Send SQL queries from DataBricks to a SQL Server using Pyspark

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc, pyspark, databricks

It is very straight forward to send custom SQL queries to a SQL database on Python.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='Electronics',
                                     user='pynative',
                                     password='pynative@#29')

sql_select_Query = "select * from Laptop" #any custom sql statement not particularly select statement
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
```

However, I have scoured the internet to do a similar task on Databricks and I haven't found any solution. It's worth mentioning that I can read from and write to SQL Server database using JDBC but I want to send a custom SQL statement for example a "bulk insert" statement that I want to execute within the SQL Server database.

Here is how I read data from SQL Server using JDBC.

```
table_name="dbo.myTable"
spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=table_name, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

Please reference this document: [SQL Databases using JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases):

Databricks Runtime contains JDBC drivers for Microsoft SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. See the Databricks runtime release notes for the complete list of JDBC libraries included in Databricks Runtime.

- This article covers how to use the DataFrame API to connect to SQL
  databases using JDBC and how to control the parallelism of reads
  through the JDBC interface. This article provides detailed examples
  using the Scala API, with abbreviated Python and Spark SQL examples
  at the end. For all of the supported arguments for connecting to SQL
  databases using JDBC, see [JDBC To Other Databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).

Python example:

```
jdbcHostname = "<hostname>"
jdbcDatabase = "employees"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user={3};password={4}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, username, password)


pushdown_query = "(select * from employees where emp_no < 10008) emp_alias"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

But the traditional jdbc connector writes data into your database using row-by-row insertion. You can use the Spark connector to write data to Azure SQL and SQL Server using bulk insert. It significantly improves the write performance when loading large data sets or loading data into tables where a column store index is used.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

/**
  Add column Metadata.
  If not specified, metadata is automatically added
  from the destination table, which may suffer performance.
*/
var bulkCopyMetadata = new BulkCopyMetadata
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(1, "Title", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 128, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(2, "FirstName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(3, "LastName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig, bulkCopyMetadata)
//df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig) if no metadata is specified.
```

Ref: [Use Spark Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/spark-connector)

HTH.

Comment: For the first Python code snippet, how did you define connectionProperties? I tried importing java.util.Properties like the scala example provides, but it failed.